# Apache Zeppelin Storage

Tags: apache-zeppelin

Is there a way to configure the naming schemes of the zeppelin notes? In my local repo they are all stored here:

```
/Users/myName/zeppelin-0.7.3-bin-all/notebook/
```

All of the folders are named with, to me at least, a mash of random characters and numbers (e.g. 2DEJKXT8). Is there any way to configure Zeppelin to use the name you give the note in the GUI to where it saves it locally? I would like to push these to a remote repository and allow someone to pull the repo and identify the notes easily. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there's no such mechanism. The note name is in note.json itself. You have to read the note.json to get the note name.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that since there is very little/none as solutions to the naming.